Does shuffling the training data cause information leakage in a time-series model with image sequences?
I am working on a predictive model for solar power production based on image sequences captured at 10-minute intervals. A single example my model receives as input consists of a sequence of images. My architecture combines CNNs and LSTMs, the CNN processes the image sequence to extract features, which are then passed to the LSTM to make use of the temporal information from the image sequence.
I am wondering whether shuffling the training data (i.e., shuffling the order of the image sequences, not the images within a sequence) during training can cause information leakage. My concern is that during training, the model might already have seen "future" images while predicting the "current" target, which could violate the temporal structure of the data. I don't provide any explicit timestamps or previous target values in the input.
By shuffling, I am hoping for better gradient updates and better batch normalization.

I've asked this in the Cross Validated forum as well (link)
